# Prove that the stochastic process can not have continuous paths.

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes

This problem is about stochastic processes, but what I really need help with is using the dominated convergence theorem in the end:

What I need to prove is that a stochastic process having these properties **can not have continuous paths:**

> 1. $t_1\ne t_2 \rightarrow W_{t_1}, W_{t_2}$ independent.
> 2. The process is stationary.
> 3. $E[W_t]= 0, \forall t$

The hint for the exercise is:

> Consider $E[(W_t^{(N)}-W_s^{(N)})^2]$ where:
>
> $$W_t^{(N)}=(-N)\vee(N\wedge W_t)$$

From what I understand, this means that the modified process is $-N$ if the original process is smaller than $-N$, it is equal to the original process, if the original process is between $-N$ and $N$, and it is $N$ if the original process is bigger than $N$. Basically we bound the absolute value.

Now I will try to solve the exercise by contradiction.

We get $E[(W_t^{(N)}-W_s^{(N)})^2]=2E[(W_t^{(N)})^2]$, since the expected value of each is 0, and they are independent. But $W_t^{(N)}$ is 0 iff  $W_t$ is 0, so $E[(W_t^{(N)})^2]$  can not be 0, because then $W_t$
 would be 0 a.s. and then we would only have a trivial process.

Notice that stationarity gives that $E[(W_t^{(N)}-W_s^{N})^2]=2E[(W_t^{(N)})^2]$ must be constant no matter what s is.

Now look at $E[(W_t^{(N)}-W_{t+1/N}^{(N)})^2]$ for $\omega$ fixed we will get N is bigger than $W_t(\omega)$ at some $N$, assuming for contradiction continuity of the path, it will happen in a neighbourhood around $W_t(\omega)$ the neighbourhood is if we hold $\omega$ fixed, it is a neighborhood in the time-parameter. Then the assumed continuity gives that we get a pointwise limit to $0$.

Now, if I could move the limit outside the integral. I would get a contradiction, because then we would must have that $E[(W_t^{(N)}-W_{t+1/N}^N)^2]\rightarrow 0$. But we showed above that this is a constant value, which has to be above $0$, or else the process is trivial.

Can you please help me finish the proof? I need a dominating function to move the limit outside the integral. But I don't see how the $N$ boundary helps us, because $N$ itself grows without bound? Any tips?

Comment: I am also curious to know why the 2 and 3 conditions are needed, intuitively it seems  that the first condition should be enough

Comment: It looks like you are missing a hypothesis. The constant function $W_t = 0$ is a solution with your current conditions. 

@Ant you do not need any assumptions more than the first and an assumption that the process is not constant.

Comment: @ChrisJanjigian Yeah, but the book didn't meantion that. I got to that in my proof, where I also assume that the process isn't trivial, maybe I should have written that as an asumption aswell even though it is not given by the exercise.

Comment: Domination: $(W_t^{(N)}-W_{s}^{(N)})^2\leqslant(2N)^2$.

Comment: @Did Thanks, but I do not see how that works. We need a dominating function that holds for all the elements in the sequence, and even though the function you have is integrable for each N, it doesn't work as N grows?

Comment: What I mean, in the dominated convergence theorem, the dominating-function g is independent of N.

Comment: No, you need domination for every fixed $N$, disproving that $W^{(N)}_{t+\epsilon}\to W^{(N)}_t$ when $\epsilon\to0$, which disproves that $W_{t+\epsilon}\to W_t$ on the event $[|W_t|\leqslant N/2]$, say.

Comment: @Did Ah thanks, now I get it. I chose $s= t+1/N$, but it would have worked with $s=t+1/k$ and letting N be fixed and let k go to infinity instead?

Answer (score 2):

There is not even a *measurable* process satisfying your conditions 1., 2., 3.

That is, suppose that $\Omega\times[0,1]\ni(t,\omega)\mapsto W_t(\omega)$ is $\mathcal F\otimes\mathcal B([0,1])$-measurable on some probablity space $(\Omega,\mathcal F,\Bbb P)$, and satisfies your conditions 1., 2., and 3. In addition, truncate as you do, if necessary, to reduce to the case in which $|W_t(\omega)|\le C$ for some constant $C\in(0,\infty)$. Finally, eliminate the trivial case by assuming that $\Bbb E[W_t^2]>0$.

Consider now the integral $I_T(\omega):=\int_0^T W_t(\omega)\,dt$, for $0<T\le 1$, which is a random variable because of the measurability assumption. By Fubini,
$$
\Bbb E[I_T^2]=\int_0^T\int_0^T\Bbb E[W_sW_t]\,ds\,dt =0,
$$
because $\Bbb E[W_sW_t]=0$ by 1. and 3. Thus $I_T=0$, a.s., for each $T$.
But $T\mapsto I_T(\omega)$ is an absolutely continuous function for each $\omega$, so differentiating with respect to $T$ and invoking Fubini and condition 2., we get $W_t=0$ a.s., for each $t$, in violation of the non-triviality assumption.