# Geometric Brownian motion with random drift and diffusion

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-integrals, stochastic-analysis

One of my finance professors claims that the following is a meaningful SDE.

$$dX_t = \delta_t\mu X_tdt + \delta_t\sigma X_tdW_t$$

Here $W$ is BM and $\mu$ and $\sigma$ are positive real constants. $(\delta_t)$ is a stochastic process such that $\delta_t \sim U[0,1]$ for each $t$. Furthermore, it is independent of $W$ and $\delta_t$ and $\delta_s$ are independent whenever $t\neq s$. There are no path properties imposed on $(\delta_t)$.

My claim is that there is no solution to this SDE. But I don't know how to show this. All I know is that $(\delta_t)$ is not exactly well-defined. The professor thinks you can just discretize the SDE and pass to the limit from that. I know that passing to the limit is just a routine operation for these people and they think things always work out when you interchange limit with anything else. That is why I find his argument hard to believe. Can someone show who is right here?

Comment: What do you mean $\delta_t$ is not exactly well enough? It's well defined - not worse than $W_t$ - in fact much simpler.

Comment: @A.S.  what i meant is that nothing is said about its paths.

Comment: These are everywhere discontinuous path. You already listed all the definition needed.

Comment: @A.S.  Exactly. So then the integrals are not well-defined. It was a mistake on my part to say that $(\delta_t)$ itself is not well defined.

Comment: Indeed I don't see a way to interpret $X_t=\int_0^t\delta_s X_s\,ds$ - there is too much freedom in $\delta_t$'s for it to be defined.

Comment: Your professor should think harder about the structure of a family $(\delta_t)$ of i.i.d. random variables **indexed by $t$ in the unit interval $[0,1]$**.

Answer (score 1):

In defining $\int_0^t \delta_s X_s\,ds$ or $\int_0^t X_s\,dW_s$, one requires, at a minimum, that the process $\delta$ be *progressively measurable*. This condition is incompatible with the assumed independence of $\delta_s$ and $\delta_t$ for all $s\not=t$. See, for example, my answer in [Prove that the stochastic process can not have continuous paths.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1631169/prove-that-the-stochastic-process-can-not-have-continuous-paths/1631253#1631253)